# Find the sum of first 'N' whole numbers by using conditions?

Tags: r

Could you please write a code in R language for the following

Find the sum of first 20 whole number by using while/for or IF conditions.

I tried writing the following code, please correct

```
x=1
while(x>0) 
{
 x<- x+1 
 sum= sum + x  
 if(x==20)
   break 
 print(sum)
}
```

Also suggest me the alternatives. so that I can learn different ways of writing a code.

Comment: Please show your code and where you are stuck.  By trying it yourself, it would also enhance your curiosity and learning factor

Comment: I think you need to initialize `sum <- 1` at the beginning.  Thus, the last element printed will be `190`.  You can check if `sum(1:19)#
[1] 190`

Comment: Thank you Akrun, Initialize sum at the beginning worked. Can you please address the following 

1. How to print only the sum of first 20 numbers.
2. Is there any alternative of writing this code.

Comment: In the loop, you are breaking at 20, so it will only do the sum until 19.  for alternatives, as I already mentioned `sum(1:19)`

Comment: BTW, you are storing the output in `sum` .  So, if you break at 20, you will anyway get the sum of 210. Check the `sum` object by typing it on the console.  By having print in a loop, it will print at each iteration.

Comment: If you need the sum to be printed once.  You can create an `if` condition i.e. `if(x == 19) print(sum)`

Comment: Very bad practice to name your object `sum`! Name it `x` or `sum1` or anything that doesn't conflict with important functions

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. You just need to position your lines of code in the correct manner. An increment operator should be after the sum variable. You should print sum before writing the break statement.

```
x=1
while(x>0) 
{
  sum= sum + x
  x = x+1
  print(sum)
  if(x==20)
    break 
  print(sum)
 }
```

Here is an alternate solution to this problem:-

```
    sum= 0
    for(i in 1:20)
    {
      sum = sum + i
    }
```